# Keep getting error in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at test.apples.main(apples.java:6)
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Random;

class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
          Random rand = new Random();
          int freq[]=new int[7];

          for(int roll=1;roll<1000;roll++) {
              ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];

          }

          System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");

          for(int face=1;face<freq.length;face++) {
              System.out.println(face+"\t" +freq[face]);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a `package test;` line?

Comment: If you're getting an "unresolved compilation error" you shouldn't even be *trying* to run your code. Fix all the compilation errors *before* you run the code. (Look in the Errors view...) Additionally, always post *complete* error messages - I'm sure the exception tells you what the unresolved compilation error is...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Package test; did the job! Should there be a Package test; line for all Java programs?

Comment: @user2998050 "test.apples" told me "class apples" should be in a "package test;". Also, that really should be `class Apples` to follow Java naming conventions - otherwise, it looks like part of the package itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `package test;` at the top of you class, then clean and rebuild your code.

Comment: Thanks. It works! Why does it work though? And should there be a package test; on top of every Java Code?

Comment: the error that you got  contains : `test.apples.main(apples.java:6)` which means that your compiler suppose that your class `apples` is inside a package called `test` .

Comment: @user2998050, If it works, than you should  accept it.